# Chrome extension modify selected textbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textbox

so I am looking for a way to modify the content of a textbox that I right-click. I know how to do it with Javascript using document.getElementById but what I do not know how to get is the id of the textbox I clicked.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.activeElement` to get the active element. For example:

```
document.activeElement.value = 'Hello!';
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be responding to a `click` event and taking the target from the event that's passed to your event handler.

Have a read of the [quirksmode Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

You might consider [using a framework to make dealing with events just a little bit easier](http://api.jquery.com/click/).